# Is there a way to shade colors in ggplot based on column values?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a gantt chart in R that is showing the timeline of a project. I would like the SHADE of the colors of the gantt chart to be based on a column value. In this case specifically I would like the shading of the colors to be based on the Forecasted column. So for example the Planning Stage would be a solid dark color since it is "Actual" and then all the other stages would be a lighter color since they are "Predicted".

Here is my code for the gantt chart, which is working fine. I just want to add the shading part and cannot figure out how.

Thank you.

```
library(tidyverse)


df <- data.frame(ProjectName = c("Project A","Project A","Project A","Project A","Project A"),
                 Year = c("2000","2000","2000","2000","2000"),
                 Forecasted = c("Actual", "Predicted","Predicted","Predicted","Predicted"),
                 StartDate = c("2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004"),
                 EndDate = c("2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005"),
                 Stage = c("Planning", "Gathering", "Starting", "Editing", "Ending"))




test_gantt <- df %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x = `StartDate`, xend =`EndDate`,
             y = `Year`, yend = `Year`,
             color = `Stage`)) +  
  geom_segment(size=8) +
  labs( 
    x = 'Start and Finish Dates', 
    y = 'Year At Time of Forecast')


test_gantt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map `Forecasted` to the `alpha` aesthetic:

```r
df %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x = `StartDate`, xend =`EndDate`,
             y = `Year`, yend = `Year`,
             color = `Stage`, alpha = Forecasted)) +  
  geom_segment(size = 8) +
  labs( 
    x = 'Start and Finish Dates', 
    y = 'Year At Time of Forecast') +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(1, 0.25))
```

[image]

Or, with a few aesthetic tweaks:

```r
df %>%  
  ggplot(aes(ymin = StartDate, ymax = EndDate, x = Year,
             color = Stage, alpha = Forecasted)) +  
  geom_errorbar(size = 8, width = 0, 
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.5, )) +
  labs( 
    x = 'Start and Finish Dates', 
    y = 'Year At Time of Forecast') +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(1, 0.25)) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set2', breaks = df$Stage) +
  theme_minimal() +
  guides(alpha = guide_none()) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]